# Implications of convergence condtions, of OLS

Tags: multiple-regression, least-squares, convergence

Given a linear regression model with k deterministic regressors,

$ y = X\beta + \epsilon, \epsilon \sim (0, \sigma^2 I_n) $

the OLS estimator of $ \beta$ is consistent if and only if

- (i)   $ (X'X)^{-1} \xrightarrow{} \infty $ as $ n \xrightarrow{} \infty $.

What I want to know is the proof that condition (i) is equivalent to:

- (ii) $ [(X'X)^{-1}]_{ii} \xrightarrow{}0$ for all $i = 1,..., k $ ($A_{ii}$ denotes the ith diagonal element of $A$,
- (iii) $tr[(X'X)^{-1}] \xrightarrow{} 0$,

and specially these two:

- (iv) $ \lambda_{max} [(X'X)^{-1}] \xrightarrow{} 0 $ ($\lambda_{max}[A] $denotes the maximum eigenvalue of $A$)
- (v) $ \lambda_{min} [(X'X)^{-1}] \xrightarrow{} \infty $ ($\lambda_{min}[A]$ denotes the minimum eigenvalue of $A$)